# How to bring NSWindow to front and to the current Space?

Tags: swift, cocoa

I'm using this code to bring up my window:

```
[self.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
[self.window setOrderedIndex:0];
```

But often it will be beneath other windows or displayed in other Space desktop that I last open it in. How do I make it always appear "in front" to the user?

*Update*
I found the answer from previously asked question; make the window show up to the top of other windows:
[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];

But how to move the app to the user's current Space?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

To bring your app to the front:

```
[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
```

Swift:

```
NSApp.activateIgnoringOtherApps(true)
```

Swift 3:

```
NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
```

Comment: Thanks! Any idea on bringing the app to the user's current Space?

Answer (score 30):

Perhaps you want:

```
  [self.window setCollectionBehavior: NSWindowCollectionBehaviorCanJoinAllSpaces];
```

Experiment with the other collection behaviors... I found `NSWindowCollectionBehaviorMoveToActiveSpace` was a bit buggy in 10.5 but it might be better now.

Comment: How do I go about learning all these subtle things without asking? At times I feel very lost in Cocoa-land.

Comment: I tend to read *all* the release notes when each new OS version comes out. There's a lot of good information in there, and it only takes an hour or two.

Comment: Read the more important programming guides and framework references, too. Start with Cocoa Fundamentals Guide and move on from there.

Comment: @NicholasRiley : I have the same problem but this answer `setCollectionBehavior` doesn't work for me in situation when there is a full-screen app, which creates a new space, my window would still show up in the original space.

Comment: Probably a bug. Spaces has never been terribly reliable or consistent, and since I wrote this, several new OS X versions have come out, each of which have substantially changed Spaces behavior.

Comment: @Gon Have you found a solution? I have the same problem

Comment: @ULazdins Maybe not a good solution. But you can try `[NSApp setActivationPolicy:]` and set the _activationPolicy_ to `NSApplicationActivationPolicyAccessory` or `NSApplicationActivationPolicyProhibited `. While doing this you'll lose your app's menu and dock icon.

Comment: Hey @Gon! Seems I did find a solution (at least it did the job for me). Try out using `[self setCollectionBehavior:NSWindowCollectionBehaviorCanJoinAllSpaces | NSWindowCollectionBehaviorTransient]; [self setLevel:NSPopUpMenuWindowLevel];`

Comment: @ULazdins :( doesn't work for me. I set my window as your code but it couldn't cover the full-screen window of other app.

Comment: @ULazdins — thanks, that combination ended up solving a problem for *me* several years later!  (Floats over fullscreen apps in 10.11 and doesn't mess up when other windows spawn.)

Answer (score 6):

Swift 5.0 +

```
 NSWindow.orderFrontRegardless()
```

Comment: This won't work for every case. But this version is OK https://stackoverflow.com/a/1740423/5302192

Comment: Can you mention some cases where this won't work?

Comment: Sure. If you are building a ".bundle" package (specifically for login window etc.), you can't use that. You also need the following code line;


```swift
    func windowDidBecomeKey(_ notification: Notification) {
        guard let window = notification.object as? NSWindow else { return }
        guard window != self.window else { return }
        self.window = window
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

The syntax seems to be a little different with Swift 2:

```
NSApplication.sharedApplication().activateIgnoringOtherApps(true)
```

Comment: `NSApp` does just return `NSApplication.sharedApplication()` singleton.

Answer (score 4):

#### Swift 3.0

```swift
NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
```

Answer (score 3):

> But how to move the app to the user's current Space?

You don't. Spaces hold windows, not applications. (That's why the `collectionBehavior` property is on NSWindow, not NSApplication.)

Comment: There is a subclass of NSWindow called FloatingPanel which can be put over spaces.

https://gist.github.com/jordibruin/8ae7b79a1c0ce2c355139f29990d5702

self.collectionBehavior.insert(.fullScreenAuxiliary)

self.collectionBehavior.insert(.canJoinAllSpaces)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to your app to come to the front, even if its minimised *and* have it activated (given active focus), then use both of these:

```
            NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
            NSApp.windows.first?.orderFrontRegardless()
```

If you only want to bring it to the front, without giving it focus, just use:

```
            NSApp.windows.first?.orderFrontRegardless()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 2.0**

```
NSApp.activateIgnoringOtherApps(true)
```

[*Helpful Programming Tips and Hacks*](https://gist.github.com/chess92)